# Beesting or bee sting

Tags: word-choice, compounds, spacing

A friend made a typo when writing "bee sting" and wrote "beesting" but apparently this is also a word according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beesting).

Does anyone actually use "beesting" if so, is it a result of some sort of localisation?

Comment: I don't recall that I've ever seen "beesting" in print.

Comment: **beestings** [The first milk produced by a cow or goat after giving birth.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beestings)

Comment: Wiktionary also lists it as a spelling variant of bee sting https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beesting#English. First I've ever seen

Comment: It is localised, in the sense that you have to know someone who keeps cows/ goats/sheep. It is in short supply, because first priority goes to the calf/ kid/ lamb. A dish of beestings in a low oven sets like an egg custard; that is because it has extra protein, extra cream, and loads of other healthy nutrients.

Comment: If it's a word (and one that's recognized by a major dictionary), then it can obviously be used. And it is also a word that used by *enough* people that it meets the criterion of being included in the dictionary. So, the fact that it *has* a dictionary definition should make it self-evident that people *do* use it.

Comment: biestings - noun plural The first milk given by a cow after calving.(haha) Websters *(1828)  webstersdictionary1828.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bee sting, beesting and bee-sting all work. But generally, beesting is not used because when you read it, you automatically want to think of it as "beest-ing". When two words are put together into a compound word, it usually only feels correct if the words sound like two clearly separate words, like playground.

Answer (score -1):

Beesting vs. bee's sting used to be the common way to distinguish between what you got from the bee and the organ of the bee that gave you the beesting.  (Personal experience - growing up in Oregon late '50s early '60s, USA)

Nowadays, at least in the States, bee sting is made the more common in articles I've read on the web; but, newspaper texts from 1880 [Albany Democrat Herald, est 1879 - Microfiche #3C01; ADH Archives] had warning of the approach of Spring, all show beesting as way of saying you got a bee sting today.  Placing a suffix "er" on sting to make a bee's stinger, or a bee stinger to distinguish between the two today? It's my own musing, but Beesting is also a last name in both America and Britain (web search 1/26/2019]. It's only conjecture that his is an old name to mean someone's occupation, like a dairy farmer with connection to "biesting."

I try to stick to the grammatical way it is used in the dictionary; but, even teachers or colleagues tend to apply my photo unless I voice concern that this is how its wrote in the dictionary today still based on past use.

Nice question!

Comment: This answer would benefit from sources.

Comment: "but, even teachers or colleagues tend to apply my photo unless I voice concern that this is how its wrote in the dictionary today still based on past use."  What does that mean?